# Prompt for credentials when accessing administrative share over network

Tags: networking, network-share, users, dfs, credentials

I have an administrative share on a server called install$ (\server\install$). This share should be accessable only for administrators and helpdesk users since it contains installers from different programms. I've a problem accessing it in the following scenario:

A user calls the helpdesk and needs a program whos installer is inside that share. The Helpdesk-worker makes msra -offerra to the client computer of the user that called in. He openes the share \server\install$ and wants to install the program. But instead of getting a window prompting for credentials it shows only an error giving an access-denied message.

When the helpdesk user openes in the same scenario the path \server\c$\ windows prompts for credentials.

How can I share a folder that it is not accessable for regular users but with the ability for delegated users to enter their credentials and access it even in a session of a regular user?

I was googling already a lot but almost everyone sais you should create a map using the option to provide different credentials but this is not an acceptable solution for me right now.

Does anybody know a sollution for this issue?

Thanks